# Build a List of Tuples from a Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list `y` of keys from a dictionary that is derived from a call to the `Google Places API`.

I would like to build a list of tuples for each point of interest:

```
lst = []
for i in range(len(y)):
    lst.append((y[i]['name'], y[i]['formatted_address'], y[i]['opening_hours']['open_now'], y[i]['rating']))
```

This works if the field is in the list and I receive a list of results that look like the one below, which is exactly what I want:

```
("Friedman's", '1187 Amsterdam Ave, New York, NY 10027, USA', True, 4.2)
```

However, the script throws an error if a desired field is not in the list `y`. How can I build a list of tuples that checks whether the desired field is in `y` before building the tuple?

Here's what I've tried:

```
    for i in range(len(y)):
        t = ()
        if y[i]['name']:
            t = t + lst.append(y[i]['name'])
        if y[i]['formatted_address']:
            t = t + lst.append(y[i]['formatted_address'])
        if y[i]['opening_hours']['open_now']:
            t = t + lst.append(y[i]['opening_hours']['open_now'])
        if y[i]['rating']:
            t = t + lst.append(y[i]['rating'])
    lst.append(t)
```

However, this doesn't work and seems very inelegant. Any suggestions?

Comment: `dict.get()` allows you to specify a "default" value if the key doesn't exist

Comment: what do you want to happen if that key wasn't in dict? you want to set in none or skip that tuple completely?

Comment: I doubt you want a list of tuples of varying sizes; how do you know which field is actually missing if the tuple is shorter than usual.

Comment: If the key isn't in the dict, I would set it to none. So, the example tuple would have a value of `none` if no `rating` were available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This list comprehension uses default values when one of the keys is not present (using [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)). I added variables so you can set the desired default values.

```
default_name = ''
default_address = ''
default_open_now = False
default_rating = 0.0

new_list = [
    (
        e.get('name', default_name),
        e.get('formatted_address', default_address),
        e.get('opening_hours', {}).get('open_now', default_open_now),
        e.get('rating', default_rating),
    )
    for e in y]
```

Answer (score 2):

For a start, you should almost never loop over range(len(something)). Always iterate over the thing directly. That goes a long way to making your code less inelegant.

For the actual issue, you could loop over the keys and only add the item if it is in the dict. That gets a bit more complicated with your one element that is a nested lookup, but if you take it out then your code just becomes:

```
for item in y:
    lst.append(tuple(item[key] for key in ('name', 'formatted_address', 'opening_hours', 'rating') if key in item))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.get) feature from `dict`.

```
y[i].get('name')
```

if `y[i]` has key `'name'` returns the value or `None`. For nested dicts, use `default` value from `get`.

```
y[i].get('opening_hours', {}).get('open_now')
```

For data structure, I recommend to keep it as an dict, and add dicts to an list.

```
lst = []
lst.append({'name': "Friedman's", "address": '1187 Amsterdam Ave, New York, NY 10027, USA'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in y:
    lst.append((v for k,v in i.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the keys method to find the keys in a dict. In your case:

```
lst=[]
fields = ('name', 'formatted_address', 'opening_hours' 'open_now', 'rating')
for i in range(len(y)):
    data = []
    for f in fields:
        if f in y[].keys():
            data.append(y[i][f])
        else:
            data.append(None)
    lst.append(set(data))
```

note that you can also get all the key, value pairs in a dict using the items() method. That would actually simply the code a bit. To make it even better, itterate over the set, rather than calling len(set) to:

```
lst=[]
fields = ('name', 'formatted_address', 'opening_hours' 'open_now', 'rating')
for i in y:
    data = []
        for key, value in i.items():
        if key in fields:
            data.append(value)
        else:
            data.append(None)
    lst.append(set(data))
```